# Django-forms on every Wagtail page, e.g. Contact form in the footer of base.html

Tags: django, django-forms, wagtail

I want to implement a contact form using django-forms into the footer of a multi-page website based on the wagtail cms framework. How can I render the form in the base.html template on every page? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest implementing it as an [inclusion template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags):

```
@register.inclusion_tag('contact_form.html')
def contact_form():
    return {'form': ContactForm()}
```

The `contact_form.html` template would contain the form's HTML. You can then include this as part of your base.html with the tag: `{% contact_form %}`

Comment: I have an issue like this @gasman but the difference is I am using the Form Builder instead of a regular django form. I tried to apply this but it didn't work. Does form builder work like a regular form or should I handle it in a different way?

Answer (score 2):

Although you want the contact form to appear on every page, I would still make a dedicated ContactFormPage AND place the form in every footer. The POST request should point to this dedicated ContactFormPage.

```
<form action='{% pageurl contact_page' %}' ...>
```

The advantages are:

- when the contact form contains errors, you are on the dedicated page
  with the focus on the task at hand.
- No need to scroll back to the footer when an error occurs.
- Easy to add a success page via RoutablePageMixin
- A sharable contact form url

The form html can be included via:

- the inclusion template tag (Gasmans answer)
- middleware (shouravs answer)

Answer (score 0):

create a `middleware.py` in the root folder where `settings.py` resides. Then add this in that file

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        request.contact_form = ContactForm()
        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```